# How to apply position fixed to an element without removing it from document flow?

Tags: html, css, flexbox, css-selectors, html5-video

I'm using flexbox and I'm trying to apply position fixed to my navbar so that it stays fixed at the top when I scroll but it when I apply position fixed to the nav it removes it from the document flow and the section element goes under the nav, how can I make it so that the nav stays fixed at top using flexbox?

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

.navbar {
  background: lightblue;
  /* position: fixed; */
  width: 100%;
  height: 60px;
  transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}

body {
  font-family: 'Barlow', sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 1.5;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.container-nav {
  max-width: 1100px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: flex;
  padding: 15px;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}

.container-nav ul {
  display: flex;
  list-style-type: none;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <nav class="navbar active">
    <div class="container-nav">
      <div class="logo">Example Logo</div>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="http://">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="http://">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="http://">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="http://">Home</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>

  </nav>
  <section class="section-1">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="side-panel">
        <ul>
          <li><a href="http://">Link</a></li>
          <li><a href="http://">Link</a></li>
          <li><a href="http://">Link</a></li>
          <li><a href="http://">Link</a></li>
          <li><a href="http://">Link</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="feed">
        <div class="card">
          <h5>Title of Post</h5>
          <img src="" alt="text">
          <div class="card-description">
            <p> Some text here.</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="card">
          <h5>Title of Post</h5>
          <img src="" alt="text">
          <div class="card-description">
            <p> Some text here.</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="card">
          <h5>Title of Post</h5>
          <img src="" alt="text">
          <div class="card-description">
            <p> Some text here.</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="card">
          <h5>Title of Post</h5>
          <img src="" alt="text">
          <div class="card-description">
            <p> Some text here.</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="card">
          <h5>Title of Post</h5>
          <img src="" alt="text">
          <div class="card-description">
            <p> Some text here.</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
</body>
```

Comment: use position:sticky